# Send SMS to Server for update

Tags: sms-gateway

I want update my server data when user send SMS to server.
My server wants listen my SMS by mobile.Is there any way to implement?
Please tell me . Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess to acheive the above task, you need to use any SMS gateways like clickatell, nowsms, etc. So when a SMS is sent to the gateway, the gateway will receive the SMS from ur device and than update your server.